# Numerical integration to solve for a variable in an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

This problem looks simple at first glance, but I have been stuck in the processing of arranging an equation of motion for an acoustics ray traversing in a non-homogenous medium in order to determine ray angles at different intervals. This equation is given in spherical coordinates as

$$\frac{d\theta}{dr} = \frac{f_e}{c} \frac{dc}{dz}-\frac{1}{R_e}$$

where $\theta$ is grazing angle of a ray (relative to the horizontal), $r$ is range along the circular path, $z$ is depth axis which lies along radii passing through the center of the sphere, $R_e$ is the earth radius, $c$ is sound speed in the medium (function of depth), and $f_e$ is defined as

$$f_e = \frac{R_e - z}{R_e}$$

This equation is the generalized Snell's Law in spherical coordinates.

My question is how should I arrange this equation to solve for $\theta$ numerically if a sound speed profile is given? The paper says that the runge kutta 4th order numerical integration is employed, but I don't know how I can implement a numerical integration technique on a differential equation like this. The variable $\theta$ seems to be troublesome too. If anyone could hint me about this, it would really appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that $d\theta/dr$ is just a given function? Or are $r$ and $z$ geometrically related?

Comment: What's known is the total circular path $r$ between 2 endpoints, which is a geodetic distance on the earth surface (z = 0) obtained from GPS and the depths, $z$, of the 2 endpoints. Also, the launch angle $\theta_1$ is known.